# WPF Problema con combobox que quita de la lista el item seleccionado y lo pone de primero

Tags: wpf

Tengo un problema con el combobox, ya que por defecto cuando selecciono un item, este se me pone de primero entonces cuando vuelvo a abrir el combobox no me aparece donde debe ir sino de primero. esto me pasa con lo siguiente. tengo un combobox con los meses desde enero a diciembre, entonces cuando el usuario va a seleccionar un mes, este se pone de primero, y cuando va a seleccionar de nuevo otro mes entonces el que selecciono anteriormente no aparece donde es(aparece de primero) y esto confunde al usuario.

la definicion del xml la tengo asi, luego por codigo lo lleno mediante un list

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboMes" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=listaMeses}" DisplayMemberPath="Nombre" SelectedValuePath="idMes"   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsReadOnly="True" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="12" TabIndex="1"  KeyDown="nextFocus"  />
```

Agradeciendo su ayuda.

Comment: Es un poco extraño, creo que nunca he visto ese comportamiento. Podría ser por no tener la propiedad `SelectedItem` definida?

Comment: si es muy extraño. pues si la tiene definida pero no de inicio en el xml, lo hago luego de llenarla en el codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resulta que estoy usando MaterialDesign y por defecto este tema coloca ese comportamiento. para quitarlo solo basta colocar en la declaracion del combobox en el xml

```
materialDesign:ComboBoxAssist.ClassicMode="True"
```

Comment: Gracias por compartir la solucion. Pasadas 48h podrás aceptar tu propia respuesta.